# How should i format my JSON and explain me some basic d3 graph node-link?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, force-layout

I want to represent my data from this JSON as a node-link using D3.js. I am new to JavaScript and D3.js . I have 3 types of data and i want to make an hierarchy between these 3 types of data . Parents > Source > Children , i want to position every parent above the source and link every parent to the source , and every child should be under the source and link them to the source :

> ## script.js

```
var width = 960,
        height = 500;

// i don't really understand what this does 
// except the .linkDistance - gives the dimension of the link
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .on("tick", tick);

// Drag the nodes
var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

//Appends the svg - the place where i draw all my items 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Select all the links and nodes , from an array ? i don't really get it
var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

// The function where i take the data from the JSON
d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  link = link.data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  node = node.data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .on("dblclick", dblclick)
      .call(drag);
});


// Here is the function where i should asign the position of the nodes and the links
// This is the most problematic and i really don't understand it
function tick(){}

// The function to fix and to clear the fix from a node
function dblclick(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
}

function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
```

> ## Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>    
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
</body>
```

> ## style.css

```
.link {
    stroke: #777;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.nodes circle{
  cursor: move;
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;

}
.node.fixed {
  fill: #f00;
}
```

> ## graph.json

```
 {
    "nodes":[
    {
        "id": "Source" , "group" :0
    },
    {
        "id":"Parent_1" , "group" : 1 
    },
    {
        "id": "Parent_2" , "group" :1
    },
    {
        "id": "Parent_3" , "group" :1
    },

    {
        "id":"Child_1" , "group":2
    },
    {
        "id":"Child_2" , "group":2
    },
    {
        "id":"Child_3" , "group":2}
    ],
    "links":[
    {
    "source":"Source","target":"Parent_1"
    },
    {
    "source":"Source","target":"Parent_2"
    },
    {
    "source":"Source","target":"Parent_3"
    },
    {
    "source":"Source","target":"Child_1"
    },
    {
    "source":"Source","target":"Child_2"
    },
    {
    "source":"Source","target":"Child_3"
    },

    ]



    }
```

If someone has the time and the mood to explain me how to format my JSON so i can use it more efficiently and to explain me how to create a node-link graph using d3 step by step or give me a demo and explain every chunk of code i would be very grateful .
If there is a problem regarding the way i asked the question or there is something unclear  please say so i can edit it. Thank you !

Comment: This is quite a big question and a lot of work to explain. Your Json looks fine to me in that it's correctly formatted and provides links (linking each child and parent to the "Source"). You can certainly use the force to group parents/children together in the SVG. Have you read https://www.dashingd3js.com/ and http://d3indepth.com/about/. If you set up a gist/block, jsfiddle, or plunkr, then you can test your code in action and people can see what's wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking through a lot of tutorials and explained code but i still don't get the idea , thank you though for the links i will check the free videos .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in a bit of a nutshell, the force places all your nodes on an svg and gives them a lot of attributes, some linked to the data, some to the behaviour of the force graph.

In general, nodes repel each other, but this behaviour can be changed by setting the strength of d3.forceManyBody.

Links will create a force between nodes, which can be used to draw the nodes together, or hold them at a set distance apart.

Generally a force will draw all the nodes towards the centre of the graph, but you can set them to be attracted to anywhere. In your case, you want a point at the top-centre (say 25% down the SVG) to attract the parent nodes (group 1) and a point botton centre (75% down the SVG) to attract the child nodes (group 2). You can set the source node to centre;

```
var position = d3.forceSimulation(graph.nodes).force("charge", d3.forceManyBody()).force("x", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height/ 2)).force("collide", d3.forceCollide(15 * R));
    nodes.each(function(d) {
        if (d.group == 0) {
            d.fx = wid / 2;//fix X value
            d.fy = wid / 2//fix Y value
        }
    });
```

if you can set up a jsfiddle or similar and get something working I might be able to see where you're stuck (it looks like your orders a bit off creating links before the data's loaded). Also, you're loading d3 version 3, as you're starting, you might as well switch to version 4 now.

Edit: this is my understanding anyway and I think the resources I linked above are probably much better!

Comment: Okay , this is kinda helpful , i am trying to rewrite the code and set up a jsfiddle as you required , it may take some time so stay put . Thanks again !